# Phonetic Search in normal search

Tags: 2010, search, 2013, keywordquery, fast

Is it possible to have phonetic search in the normal search and not only in the peoplesearch?

I read that in SP2010 the KQL does not support phonetic search in Non-People-Searches. What about SP2013 and what are the problems there?

I tried it with the REST-API but ?enablephonetic=true only works for firstnames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phonetic search is only for people searching.  This is still the case in 2013.  Its more specifically called "Phonetic People Matching".

Comment: thanks. so if i wanted something like a "phonetic search" in 2010/2013 i have to do it with a thesaurus? i'm i getting this right?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to manually provide replacements or synonyms for words searched for you can use thesaurus files: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361734(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: And here is the documentation for 2013: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219579.aspx

Comment: @JohnChapman : In SP2013 we have several verticals, On `Everything` vertical I am adding a result block using query rule to show `People Result`. I am wondering if this block can show phonetic(nickname) search results. Because it works in People vertical but not in everything inspite of result block.